# how to append new blank page at the end of pdf file using python

Tags: python, pdf, pdf-generation, pypdf

I am using PyPDF2 lib but it just overwrites the blank page and don't append at the end of PDF file.
Here's my code.

```
#this is the file i'm creating
file1 = canvas.Canvas("Statements.pdf", pagesize=letter)
file1.drawString(100,400,"HELLOOOO")
file1.save()

# using this code i want to append blank page at the end but it overwrites 
#with blank page
with open("Statements.pdf", 'rb') as input:
pdf=PdfFileReader(input)
numPages=pdf.getNumPages()

outPdf=PdfFileWriter()
outPdf.cloneDocumentFromReader(pdf)
outPdf.addBlankPage()
outStream=file('Statements.pdf','wb')
outPdf.write(outStream)
outStream.close()
```

Comment: try using `PdfWriter.appendPagesFromReader()`

Comment: Thanks for your response. i have tried this also but it still overwrites with blank page. previous data vanished.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be an issue with `cloneDocumentFromReader` see: https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2/issues/219
If you do not attempt to add a blank page but just perform the clone, you end up with an empty file.

The following works for me (Linux), as referenced by SPYBUG96

```
import PyPDF2
import shutil
a = open("some_pdf_file.pdf", 'rb')
pdf=PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(a)
numPages=pdf.getNumPages()
outPdf=PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()
outPdf.appendPagesFromReader(pdf)
#outPdf.cloneDocumentFromReader(pdf)
outPdf.addBlankPage()
outStream=open('Amended.pdf','wb')
outPdf.write(outStream)
outStream.close()
a.close()
#Copy amended file back over the original
shutil.copyfile('Amended.pdf','some_pdf_file.pdf')
```

Note: you could use `shutil.move('Amended.pdf','some_pdf_file.pdf')`

Comment: Thanks alot it works. What if i attempts to add blank page in same file whom i open to read (a = open("some_pdf_file.pdf", 'rb'))  and write in same file. (outStream=open('some_pdf_file.pdf','wb')). i tried this thing and page was added successfully but whole pdf file was empty. what should i do to preserve my previous data and blank page also added at the end. Thanks

Comment: The easiest way is to copy the amended file over the original. See my amended post.